Reading and writing a MULTIPART_FORM_DATA message with FormHttpMessageConverter
I'm trying to read and write a MULTIPART_FORM_DATA message directly with a FormHttpMessageConverter.
While the serialization works, the deserialization fails. Instead of properly parsing the keys and values, the outputMessage gets just directly written to the MultiValueMap as a single entry.
@Test
fun `test FormHttpMessageConverter`() {
    val formHttpMessageConverter = FormHttpMessageConverter()

    // Writing form data
    val formData = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
    formData.add("field1", "foo")
    formData.add("field2", "bar")
    formData.forEach { println("${it.key}: ${it.value}") }
    println("-------------------------------------------")

    val outputMessage = MockHttpOutputMessage()
    formHttpMessageConverter.write(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, outputMessage)
    val formDataString = outputMessage.body.toString()

    // Reading form data
    val inputMessage = MockHttpInputMessage(formDataString.toByteArray())
    val readFormData = formHttpMessageConverter.read(null, inputMessage) as MultiValueMap<String, String>
    readFormData.forEach { println("${it.key}: ${it.value}") }
}

Output:
field1: [foo]
field2: [bar]
-------------------------------------------
--JsuTq6lvPfNRO4XwfDLI6n7kzZchk62-ow
Content-Disposition: form-data; name: ["field1"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3

foo
--JsuTq6lvPfNRO4XwfDLI6n7kzZchk62-ow
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3

bar
--JsuTq6lvPfNRO4XwfDLI6n7kzZchk62-ow--]

